# How can i extract values from cassandra output using python?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra

I'm trying to connect cassandra database through python using cassandra driver .And it went successful with out any problem . When i tried to fetch the values from cassandra ,it has some formatted output like Row(values) .

python version 3.6

package : cassandra

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('employee')
k=session.execute("select count(*) from users")
print(k[0])
```

Output :

Row(count=11)

Expected  :

11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/getting_started/#executing-queries):

> By default, each row in the result set will be a named tuple. Each row will have a matching attribute for each column defined in the schema, such as name, age, and so on. You can also treat them as normal tuples by unpacking them or accessing fields by position.

So you can access your data by name as `k[0].count`, or by position as `rows[0][0]`

Please read [Getting started](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/getting_started/) document from driver's documentation - it will answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra reply everything using something called row factory, which by default is a named tuple.

In your case, to access the output you should access k[0].count.